# React js, why doesn't my component re-render when I change the value of open?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that renders perfectly the first time, but no changes to the passed in variables will affect anything, even though passing in true or false for open seems to always work fine. Why doesn't this work?

```
const ChatWindow = ({ open, prevContent }) => {

  var content = prevContent.messages.map(message => (
          <Message player={message.player} text={message.text} />));

  const openClose = () => {
    if(open){
      open = false;
    } else {
      open = true;
    }
    console.log(open);
  }



  return (
    <div className="ChatWindow">
      <div className="openWindow" onClick={() => openClose()}>{open ? "X" : "O"}</div>

      <div className="Content">
        {content}
      </div>

      <style jsx>{`
       .ChatWindow {
          opacity: ${open ? "1.0" : "0.3"};
        }
        .Content {
          max-height: ${open ? "400px" : "0px"};
          opacity: ${open ? "1.0" : "
          overflow-y: ${open ? "scroll" : "hidden"};
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cause a re-render on open/close, for that its preferred to maintain a state either in parent of in the current component

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state= {
      open: false;
   }
   openClose = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({open: !prevState.open}))
  }
  render() {
   const { prevContent } = this.props;
   var content = prevContent.messages.map(message => (
          <Message player={message.player} text={message.text} />));

    const { open } = this.state;
      return (
        <div className="ChatWindow">
          <div className="openWindow" onClick={() => this.openClose()}>{open ? "X" : "O"}</div>

          <div className="Content">
            {content}
          </div>

          <style jsx>{`
           .ChatWindow {
              opacity: ${open ? "1.0" : "0.3"};
            }
            .Content {
              max-height: ${open ? "400px" : "0px"};
              opacity: ${open ? "1.0" : "
              overflow-y: ${open ? "scroll" : "hidden"};
            }
          `}</style>
        </div>
      )
    }

}
```

Comment: ok this makes sense, but then how do I pass variables into this component from my app? Like I need to be able to define "open" and "prevContent" when I place this component.

Comment: prevContent is a prop and open we are storing in the components state itself,

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand. In my chat window I declare prevContent={etc.}, but now how do I access that within this new form of state componenet?

Comment: I just updated my answer,`const { prevContent } = this.props`

Answer (score 1):

React responds to changes in the component's state/props, not just a change in any variable.  Make your `open` property part of the component's state and use `setState` to update it.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open: false,
    };
}
```

Comment: wait, how would I place the constructor into my current component? I'm really new to this and don't understand the syntax yet? Every time I place it right before my return method, I get syntax errors..

Comment: You need to switch from a function component to a class component to use state

Comment: True.  Good catch.